# Misaligned custom font in TextInputEditText

Tags: android, css, fonts, material-design

Using a custom font makes the text look shifted a bit to the top:

[image]

After looking up the problem, it seems like it occurs due to the font issue as it looks in the following screenshot, letters are not centered:

[image]

Is there a way to center letters?

Here's the font I use:
https://arbfonts.com//wp-content/fonts/new-arabic-fonts//Tajawal-Medium-2.ttf

This is the result of what @Ki suggested by centering all letters.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `line-height`?

Comment: This is more like a hardcoded way, the issue is from the font itself. So, I need a way to fix the TTF file to apply changes globally instead of setting that code for every text in the app.

Comment: https://birdfont.org/ is a free software that allows editing of .TTF files and vector graphics

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as expected, I tried centering all letters using the software you provided. I updated my question with the result. I provided the font link in my question, can you try and let me know if it works for you? I may be doing it wrong. If you're free of course.